# If an application program run in RAM where does Operating system run?

Tags: operating-system

I have read that Operating System is loaded in main memory (RAM) when computer boots up. Also, application programs are loaded into main memory (RAM) for execution. How do both of these run simultaneously in main memory? Does the operating system stop its execution when an application program is running?

Comment: it looks to me like you are confusing some things: RAM is just storage, it doesn't execute anything. The CPU execute programs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a good overview of these areas, so I'll try to help.

Memory (RAM) can be visualized as a collection of lockers. Each locker can store something independently of all other lockers. Each locker has a number, so you can find a particular locker easily. In RAM, the locker is a byte that can store a value between zero and `255`, and the locker number is an address. Better than a locker; you can open the byte at address zero, then the byte at address `1000000` instantly. You don't have to walk down a long hallway. That is what the R in RAM refers to: Random, as in Random Access Memory. Essentially every location takes the same amount of time to access.

Machines have a lot of RAM, on the order of billions of bytes. Even very big operating systems do not need all of RAM; if they require 50 million bytes, that is only 50 / 1000 or 5% of what is now considered a small system. That leaves 950 million bytes for programs to use. If every program was as big as the operating system, you could run 950/50 = 19 of them. There are tricks to permit running even more.

One of the fundamental jobs of the operating system is to provision resources like RAM to applications, and make sure that applications cannot snoop on or modify each others RAM without prior arrangement. To do this, the operating system typically uses a trick where program addresses are indirectly translated to RAM addresses under control of the operating system. This way, all applications can think they have ram at (say) address 4194304. This trick is called an MMU (Memory Management Unit), and the details start to explode at this point.

Review:

1. RAM is a collection of places to store numbers, and each storage place has a unique address.
2. There is lots of RAM, so we just have to divvy it up between applications.
3. We can keep applications RAM separate and secret from other applications.
4. The operating system only uses a relatively small amount of RAM.